# Two threads access the same file with mutex preventing race condition from occurring

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, mutex

I have two threads (labeled as 0 and 1).

Each process accesses an input file (f1, f2/ global variable) and an output file. (fout1, fout2/ global variable)

Once a thread(say #0) finishes its job according to a certain standard, it will then help the other thread(#1).

So thread#0 can fscanf(f2) and fprintf(f2) now while the commands are in the zone protected by mutex.

When the input data is small (100, 500, 1000, 2000 ... etc), the thread finishing its job earlier will help the other one.

for example:

- fout1: a(#1), b(#1), c(#1) ... ← handled by thread#1
- fout2(finish first): A(#1), B(#1), C(#1) ...

But when the data size is big (ex 10000), the two threads will only take care of "their own job" separately.
The thread finish first doesn't seem to help the other one.

for example:

- fout1: a(#0), b(#0), c(#0) ... ← handled by thread#0
- fout2(finish first): A(#1), B(#1), C(#1) ... ← handled by thread#1

Can anyone help me with this? (LinuxOS)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define queueL 4

int Length, fd, rule1, rule2, done[2]={0}, breakflag[2]={0};
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t threadMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
FILE *f1, *f2, *fout1, *fout2;

void *tmpF(void *t) {
int tid = (int)t, var;
int rule=(tid%2)==0?rule1:rule2;
FILE *f=(tid%2)==0?f1:f2;
FILE *fout=(tid%2)==0?fout1:fout2;

printf("rule[%d]: %d\n", tid, rule);
pthread_mutex_lock(&threadMutex);
printf("in thread#%d\n", tid);
fprintf(fout, "Thread[%d]\nmatched numbers:\n", tid);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&threadMutex);
sleep(1);

while (1) {
    if (tid%2==0) pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    else pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    if (fscanf(f,"%d",&var)==1) {
        if (var%rule==0)
            fprintf(fout, "%d(#%d) ", var,tid);
    }
    else {
        printf("Thread[%d] finishes it own process\n", tid);
        breakflag[tid] = 1;
        if (tid%2==0) pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        else pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
        break;
    }
    if (tid%2==0) pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    else pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
}

if (tid==0) {
    rule = rule2;
    f = f2;
    fout = fout2;
}
else {
    rule = rule1;
    f = f1;
    fout = fout1;
}

while (1) {
    if (tid%2==0) pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    else pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

    if (breakflag[1-tid]==1) break;
    if (fscanf(f,"%d",&var)==1) {
        if (var%rule==0)
            fprintf(fout, "%d(#%d) ", var,tid);
    }
    else {
        printf("Thread[%d] helps Thread[%d] finishes it own process\n", tid, 1-tid);
        breakflag[1-tid] = 1;
        if (tid%2==0) pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
        else pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        break;
    }
    if (tid%2==0) pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    else pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
}

pthread_exit((void*)t);
}

int main()
{
int var, i, N=100, t;
char cha[20];
srand(time(NULL));
Length=0;

printf("How many numbers to produce?: ");
scanf("%d",&N);
FILE *f = fopen("data.txt","w");
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    fprintf(f,"%d ",rand()%200+1);
}
fclose(f);

f1 = fopen("data.txt","r");
f2 = fopen("data.txt","r");
fout1 = fopen("lab5_2_out1.txt","w");
fout2 = fopen("lab5_2_out2.txt","w");

f = fopen("rule.txt","r");
fscanf(f,"%s%s%s%s%s%d",cha,cha,cha,cha,cha,&rule1);
fscanf(f,"%s%s%s%s%s%d",cha,cha,cha,cha,cha,&rule2);
fclose(f);

pthread_mutex_lock(&threadMutex);
void *status;
pthread_t th[2], rdOut[2];
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

pthread_create(&th[0],&attr,tmpF,(void*)0);
pthread_create(&th[1],&attr,tmpF,(void*)1);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&threadMutex);

printf("main thread before join...\n");
pthread_join(th[0],&status);
pthread_join(th[1],&status);

fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);
fclose(fout1);
fclose(fout2);

printf("main thread ends...\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You doing the same homework as @fatffatable ?

Comment: Inside your `while (1)` loops, the whole body is protected by the mutex. So there will be no parallel processing, i.e. the second thread is not really "helping" if the first one has to wait. Might not be your problem, just a thought.

Comment: @MartinJames i saw his question, it's not the same. i didn't encounter his problem

Comment: @KarstenKoop Do you mean mutex1/mutex2 or threadMutex? I use **mutex1/mutex2** to protect **f1/f2** and **fout1/fout2** inside `while (1)` and unlock it after each iteration. Is that alright?